# mark image files for copy in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I'm looking at a bunch of image files through Windows Photo Viewer. When I see a good one I copy it over to a different directory.

Is there a faster way of marking the files I want and then when I go through all the images just copy over the marked ones?

I'd rather just do this in Windows natively and not use an external program if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Open Windows Explorer.
2. Set the display to Extra Large icons.
3. Hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> when left-clicking the photos you want.
4. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from source directory and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> into target directory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the 'Extra Large icons' are still too small for me to distinguish any detail to let me know if it's good or not.

Comment: What about [Windows Photo Gallery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Photo_Gallery)? You get it via optional Windows Updates, so I don't know if you'd count this as an external program.